# Additional fonts required

Tags: gnome, libreoffice, fonts

When I start LibreOffice, Gnome shows a notification that says:

"Additional fonts required.
An application is requesting additional fonts."

I tried all methods to refresh the cache of the fonts directory also deleted the fonts cache directory and refresh it again but not solved. Actually, this makes only a problem in the user interface where the number of pages counts and words counts don't appear in the Writer status bar. so I can't see the words count until I click on its place in the status bar to show me the word count window. I was using LibreOffice 6.3 with the same problem so I decide to upgrade to 7.2 but the problem is still there.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome.

when I try to reinstall Ubuntu-Desktop I get errors:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,592 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 243145 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-desktop_1.417.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-desktop (1.417.5) over (1.417.5) ...
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.2.2~18.04.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient'
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up ubuntu-desktop (1.417.5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Take a look at this article. https://theserif.net/fonts/how-to-add-fonts-to-libreoffice/

Comment: @David Thanks for your comment. the article you are recommended is talking about adding fonts to the LibreOffice for writing propose but my problem is there are fonts missed for the user interface of the LibreOffice.

Comment: Maybe clarify in the question. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @David I modified this sentence to make it more clear "this makes only a problem in the user interface where the number of pages counts and words counts don't appear in the Writer status bar"

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling LibreOffice?

Comment: @Jos, yes and I already mentioned that. actually, I deleted the old one and installed the latest version (7.2)